# Why OneToOne relation doesn't works as expected?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have 2 entitie. User:

```
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Entity
public class User {

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String email;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
  private Authentication authentication; 
}
```

and Authentication:

```
@Table(name = "AUTHENTICATIONS")
@Entity
public class Authentication {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "login_id")
  private String loginId;//openId login

  @JsonIgnore
  private String password;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
}
```

And I have service which provides registration for new users:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User createUser(UserRegistrationForm form) {
    Authentication authentication = new Authentication();
    authentication.setPassword(form.getPassword());
    User user = new User();
    user.setAuthentication(authentication);
    user.setEmail(form.getEmail());
    user.setName(form.getLogin());
    authentication.setUser(user);
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

And my problem is method userRepository.save() returns infinitely nested objects:

```
{"id":1,"name":"myName","email":"myemail@gmail.com","authentication":{"id":1,"loginId":null,"user":{"id":1,"name":"myName","email":"myemail@gmail.com","authentication":{"id":1,"loginId":null,"user":{"id":1,"name":"myName","email":"myemail@gmail.com","authentication":{"id":1,"loginId":null,"user":{"id":1,"name":"myName","email":"myemail@gmail.com","authentication":{"id":1,"loginId":null,"user":{"id":1,"name":"myName","email":"myemail@gmail.com","authentication":{"id":1,"loginId":null,"user":{"id":1,"name":"
```

What am I doing wrong? Help to understand how it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's json which returns nested objects ... not your repository !

you are using jackson ?
add @JsonManagedReference on one side and @JsonBackReference on the other

Comment: no problem ;) ... can you please accept the answer then ? it may be useful for others

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

```
 user.setAuthentication(authentication);
...
    authentication.setUser(user);
```

You have a nested reference between `user` and `authentication`

Comment: Thanks for getting a support. How can I save user and assign with his own auth object in DB?